# Does the boosted staking feature of Coinbase One apply to Ethereum?

Tags: ether, coinbase, staking, reward, stake

Coinbase sells the Coinbase One service which costs $30 / month. This provides 'boosted' staking which "reduc[es] the commission that Coinbase takes from the relevant protocol payout." The "standard commission is 35% for ADA, ATOM, DOT, SOL and XTZ (26.3% for eligible Coinbase One members) and 25% for ETH." This shows a reduction in the commission for protocols other than ETH. Does boosted staking reduce the commission for ETH?

- [New updates to Coinbase One: zero trading fees, boosted staking
  rewards & partnerships](https://www.coinbase.com/blog/new-updates-to-coinbase-one-zero-trading-fees-boosted-staking-rewards-and)
- [Coinbase One](https://www.coinbase.com/one)
- [Earn rewards with staking](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/coinbase-staking/rewards/earn-rewards-with-staking)
- [Coinbase pricing and fees disclosures](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/pricing-and-fees/fees)